# LIMIT only on one of tables in JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have two tables `product` and `gallery`. Each product can have multiple images in `gallery`. When I try to get LIMITed 5 products along with their `gallery` records, I do a JOIN like:

```
SELECT * FROM `product` p LEFT JOIN `gallery` g ON p.product_id = g.product_id 
LIMIT 0,5
```

This query returns me 5 records (i.e. only 3 products) like:

```
product_id   name   image
1            p1     im1.jpg
1            p1     im3.jpg
1            p1     xyz.jpg
2            p2     abc.jpg
3            p3     tuy.jpg
```

What I need is exactly 5 products, no matter how many `gallery` records against each product are and no matter how many total records be. Here's my expected result:

```
product_id   name   image
1            p1     im1.jpg
1            p1     im3.jpg
1            p1     xyz.jpg
2            p2     abc.jpg
3            p3     tuy.jpg
4            p4     a32.jpg
4            p4     t22.jpg
4            p4     a13c.jpg
5            p5     t34y.jpg
```

How can I do this via a single query?

Comment: can you post expected output? do you mean you need distinct products?

Comment: @AshReva Plz check, I edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this you can select the 5 products by subquery and join with images so you will get the records for 5 products,no matter how many images each product have

```
SELECT * FROM
 `gallery` g
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM  `product` LIMIT 5) p
 ON( p.product_id = g.product_id )
```

Comment: Thx. Why not LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Left will return all the images even that are not related to the 5 products from subquery so i use inner join

Comment: What if I use LEFT JOIN and `WHERE g.product_id IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Yes it will work same as inner join by using above where clause

Answer (score 0):

To get five images for each product (which is a misinterpretation of the question):

```
SELECT *
FROM `product` p LEFT JOIN
     `gallery` g
     ON p.product_id = g.product_id 
WHERE 5 <= (select count(*)
            from gallery g2
            where g2.product_id = g.product_id and g2.image <= g.image
           );
```

An alternative way is to put the images into one comma separated column:

```
select p.*, substring_index(group_concat(distinct image), ',', 5) as images
from product p left join
     gallery g
     on p.product_id = g.product_id
group by p.product_id;
```

Comment: Thanks but the one by @M Khalid is more simple.

Comment: @aceph . . . No.  That answer is correct and this one is not, because I answered the wrong question.  I will leave this up anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your query like this,

```
SELECT * FROM `product` p LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM `gallery` LIMIT 0,5) as g ON    p.product_id = g.product_id
```

But, using sub-query cost your performance.